# circular scrollview through NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have created sample circular UIScrollview.it works fine.but i want to scroll through NSTimer automatically.when I implemented , after reaching last item in scrolliview, it did not repeat like looping.any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that animate method write below condition i think it will work

```
scrollView.contentOffset.x=(scrollView.contentOffset.x>=scrollView.contentSize.width-scrollView.frame.size.width)?0:scrollView.contentOffset.x+5;
```

Comment: according to you, i have done code and called scrollview1 method through NSTimer,but it not looping,after it reaches last item,it starts from left side.but my needs to be appended from the last item..pls any help?

Comment: have you add images on scroll view

Comment: i forgot to handle didendaccelarating method